# Toggling children visibility in jQuery accordion-style menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, accordion

I have a simple accordion-style menu which opens/closes its children with a help of jQuery: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errata/RtG2A/).

If I click on menu items everything works fine - children of selected items are displayed, while all other unnecessary children items hide. However, I'd like to be able to open menu tree based on some variable passed (`id`).

So, in this jsFiddle I created manual links (on right side) which should show corresponding item in menu (expand all parents) and hide all others. I managed to toggle only first-level children when clicked on manual links, but when I click on let's say 4th-level link (cat 11 in my example), nothing happens. What I'd like to do is to expand all parents of selected item and collapse all other which are not in selected child's the tree path.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Does this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAurj/4/) perform as desired?

Comment: Well, mostly yes, that's the right way for sure :) I see that when `toggle cat 11` is clicked all the parents expand properly, although some of children are not collapsing sometimes, e.g. try to click on `toggle cat 1` and then `toggle cat 11`. `cat 1` should collapse. Same is when clicking `toggle cat 5`, `toggle cat 6` and `toggle cat 11`. In that scenario `cat 6` should collapse. Thanks a lot for effort, this is very close! I'll try to check out what is happening here and see if I will be able to adjust it even more :)

Comment: How about [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/WAurj/5/)?

Comment: Much better :) I was trying to work on your previous version and implement it and have noticed that when `cat 1` is selected, parent element, which is in my case bunch of text, is replaced with `+` symbol. I will try to implement this last version, but seems that this is very very close :) Thank you one more time!

Comment: Can you lease post this as an answer so I can accept it? Essentially you did post a proper solution, and I managed to handle my other 'problems'  :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAurj/5/) does what you want.

I haven't tested with any more levels than your original fiddle had, but I think all of the parent, sibling, and "cousin" elements are accounted for and toggled appropriately depending on what the user clicks.